# how to pass eventData in eventRequest of JavaScript Web SDK for Dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

After getting uid of the logged user using `signInWithPopup`.
I am passing this uid to `dialogflow` by event trigger mechanism.

So I have added an event with name "login" and calling using JavaScript Web SDK for Dialogflow like this.

[image]

```
client.eventRequest('login',eventData = {
    "uid" : user.uid,
});
```

And at fulfillment side I am accessing parameter "uid" like

```
function loginAction(agent) {
    let user = agent.getContext('user').parameters;
    console.log("logged Uid " + user.uid);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    agent.add('Welcome');
}
```

Output in log is like:

```
logged Uid 
{"uid":"","uid.original":""}
```

Also in github repo of [JavaScript Web SDK for Dialogflow](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client) no any example is given for sending parameter with `eventRequest()`

Comment: Do you have a parameter for the `action.login` intent called `uid`?

Comment: yes I have that in parameter

Comment: what is the value of `agent. parameters.uid` in the `loginAction` intent handler?

Comment: its just a string

Comment: is the value of `agent.parameters.uid` the value you are looking for?

Comment: yes I want to pass that parameter while triggering the event

Comment: Where are you expecting that uid to be where it is not?  If the uid is in the agent.parameters.uid attribute isn't it where it should be?

Comment: I am using google's signUpWithPopup() at client side to use google authentication for web chatbot but how can I manage the session? for managing session currently I am using context which contains uid and username sent from client side using parameters.

Comment: And for that I am using one intent to detect this format with e.g. "login [uid] [username]" Is this is good way?

Comment: But I want to trigger event "login" and pass parameters as uid, username and above is my attempt to do so but it is not working don't know why?

Comment: What is "not triggering" as you'd expect it to?  It sounds like a) you're triggering an event via the Javascript SDK, b) the event is matched to the correct intent in Dialogflow c) the intent triggers the webhook correctly and d) the webhook is called with the parameters you want (`agent.parameters.uid`).  What are you expecting to happen that doesn't happen?

Comment: I'm able to trigger event but how to send parameters using javascript SDK. In GitHub documentation of that SDK no any docs are provided about that. It only consists of how to call event, isn't it?